# Problema menú responsive en Telefonos

Tags: jquery-mobile

Resulta que la web es esta. www.goldviajes.com. Aún la estamos perfilando.
Pero el problema lo tenemos en el menú. Al pinchar en el menú en un teléfono el botón actúa, pero el menú no se visualiza.
El asunto es que poniendo el PC en modo tableta, simulando responsive, el menú funciona a las mil maravillas.

Pero a la hora de la verdad no se visualiza.

Answer (score 0):

Iria bien saber como has programado el código, si tienes la función que abre el menú te puedo ayudar.

A ver si te sirve este pequeño ejemplo:

```
$('.boton').on('click',function(){
     $('.menu').slideToggle('slow');
})
```

Si pones tu código lo puedo revisar i ver.